# How to blend multiple semi-transparent GeoTIFFs

Tags: geotiff-tiff

How to blend multiple overlapping semi-transparent GeoTIFFs to single semi-transparent GeoTIFF on Linux (GDAL...) ?

Comment: I would evaluate first VRT with derived bands https://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html#gdal_vrttut_derived_c

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the software you're using, what you tried so far and where you're stuck?

Comment: I use linux and tried nothing yet because I found nothing how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with the following script:

(input files are `layer1.tiff` and `layer2.tiff`; output is `blended.tiff`)

```
FORMULA='(1.0*A*B/255.0 + 1.0*C*D/255.0*(1.0 - 1.0*B/255.0)) / (1.0*B/255.0 + 1.0*D/255.0*(1.0 - 1.0*B/255.0))'

# compute each color band
gdal_calc.py -A layer1.tiff -B layer1.tiff --A_band=1 --B_band=4 -C layer2.tiff -D layer2.tiff --C_band=1 --D_band=4 --outfile=R.tiff --calc="$FORMULA" --type=Byte
gdal_calc.py -A layer1.tiff -B layer1.tiff --A_band=2 --B_band=4 -C layer2.tiff -D layer2.tiff --C_band=2 --D_band=4 --outfile=G.tiff --calc="$FORMULA" --type=Byte
gdal_calc.py -A layer1.tiff -B layer1.tiff --A_band=3 --B_band=4 -C layer2.tiff -D layer2.tiff --C_band=3 --D_band=4 --outfile=B.tiff --calc="$FORMULA" --type=Byte

# compute alpha
gdal_calc.py -A layer1.tiff --A_band=4 -B layer2.tiff --B_band=4 --outfile=A.tiff --calc='255.0*(1.0*B/255.0 + 1.0*D/255.0 - 1.0*B/255.0*D/255.0)' --type=Byte

# join bands
gdal_merge.py -separate -o blended.tiff R.tiff G.tiff B.tiff A.tiff
```